# How to load a directory of different files Excel and CSV in multiple tables on database with Talend?

Tags: mysql, talend

I need to load a directory of different files (Excel and CSV) without any relation between them in multiple tables on database, every file must be loaded in its own table without any transformation.

I tried to do this using `TfileList ==> TfileInputExcel ==> tMySQLOutput` but it doesn't work because I need a lot of outputs.

Comment: is the number of columns and column order same in all these excel and csv files...And does your directory contains sub directories for excel and csv files or its only the extension in file name which tells whether a file is excel or csv

Comment: all files in the directory are different and has different name, each file is supposed to reflect different kind of information so my understanding is to load each file in a separate table in the DB. the directory doesn't contain any sub directories and we use the name and  the extension of file to differenciate between the files, every day we receive a new files in the same directory while the files from yesterday are archived in different location,the problem here is for the same dated file it could happen that it doesn't contain the same number/order of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but it seems like you want something generic enough that will work with just one flow for all your files.

You might be able to accomplish that using dynamic schemas. See here for further guidance: https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21887. You will probably  need at least 2 flows, one for the CSV files and one for the XLS files. You can filter the files for each flow by their extension in the tFileList component.

But if you are new to Talend, I encourage you to avoid this approach. It might be very hard to understand and use dynamic schemas. Instead, I would recommend you have one flow for each file.

Comment: all files in the directory are different and has different name, each file is supposed to reflect different kind of information so my understanding is to load each file in a separate table in the DB. the directory doesn't contain any sub directories and we use the name and the extension of file to differenciate between the files, every day we receive a new files in the same directory while the files from yesterday are archived in different location,the problem here is for the same dated file it could happen that it doesn't contain the same number/order of columns.

Comment: i noticed that the dynamic schemas is only available in Talend enterprise products. i have the open source one so i can't use it . my problem is how to load multiple different files in multiple tables in mysql DB .

Comment: plz can somebody help me , i can't find an answer

Comment: Ok, from what I understand, the files can have the same name, but different columns depending on the day. If the schema changes are predicable (for example if there are 4 different schemas that the files might have), you can use the tSchemaCheck to see which schema the file has, and then process each file according to its schema that day. However, if the schema is not predictable, you could still read it with a tFileInputFullRow and use some custom java code (in a tJavaRow) to handle it dynamically.